# printing mobile numbers with sed

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have input records like this :

```
Addison Clark asdj asjdasjd asjdasndasd 9098890099  BE ME BA
Debby Adam asjhdj23 j23 j123jn123 123jnwjb12hg3  123jh123 jhj23 123 9283774849 MBA MIB PHD BE BA
```

where first two columns contain the first and the last name and among rest of the text in each line can contain anything including mobile number. My target is to extract first and last name and the mobile number.

I have tried

```
sed -re 's/^(\b\w+\b) (\b\w+\b).*([0-9]{10}).*/\1 \2 \3/'
```

which works totally fine , but when I change it to

```
sed -re 's/^(\b\w+\b) (\b\w+\b).*([0-9]+).*/\1 \2 \3/'
```

It prints only the first digit in mobile no but not the entire mobile numbers . Any idea what may be wrong with the second command ?

Comment: Can it be anywhere within the line? mobile number? and is there a fixed length to it?

Comment: yes the mobile number is fixed length 10 digits . it can be anywhere in the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Awk` with the default field separator,

```
awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /^[[:digit:]]{10}$/) { number=$i; break } } printf "%s %s %s\n",$1,$2,number }' file
Addison Clark 9098890099
Debby Adam 9283774849
```

The idea is to loop from the `3rd` field to end of the file to match the mobile number pattern and once found break out of the loop and print rest of the fields.

Look at this, [`regEx` tester page](https://regex101.com/r/XASr73/1), which said for your `[0-9]+` match,

```
3rd Capturing Group ([0-9]+)
Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]+
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (ASCII 48) and 9 (ASCII 57)
```

Look at what the `+` quantifier means taken from [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html),

> Limiting Repetition
>
> There's an additional quantifier that allows you to specify how many times a token can be repeated. *The syntax is {min,max}, where min is zero or a positive integer number indicating the minimum number of matches, and max is an integer equal to or greater than min indicating the maximum number of matches*. If the comma is present but max is omitted, the maximum number of matches is infinite. **So {0,1} is the same as ?, {0,} is the same as *, and {1,} is the same as +. Omitting both the comma and max tells the engine to repeat the token exactly min times**.

So `[0-9]+` literally means match single or more characters, with minimum being one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but I am looking for whats wrong with my second command

Comment: @user3369871: Refer my update on authoritative attempt on why your regex failed.

Comment: Thanks I get it now , .*   being greedy matches to the maximum when using [0-9]+   and [0-9]+ can match only one.